# How come my nav bar dropdown animation is not working?

Tags: javascript, css, sass

When I click on the navigation toggle icon, the navigation menu is not appearing in a "slide down" fashion. It should slide down when it appears (when the class of .show is added).

I have set the height properties in the @keyframe rule. I have set an overflow property to "hidden". Still, I cannot get the navigation to animate and slide down when it appears.

HTML:

```
<header class="header">
    <div class="header--one">
        <div class="header__logo-box">
            <a class="header__logo">myBlog</a>
        </div>
        <i class="header__navtoggle fa fa-bars"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="header--two">
        <nav class="header__nav">
            <a href="#" class="header__nav-item">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#" class="header__nav-item">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#" class="header__nav-item">Link 3</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

SCSS:

```
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? family=Roboto+Slab:400,700&display=swap');

 *,*::before,*::after{
     box-sizing: inherit;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
 }

 html{
     font-size: 62.5%;
 }

 body{
     box-sizing: border-box;
     color: #777;
     font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
     background:#f2f2f2;
 }


 .header{
     background:#333;
     display:flex;
     font-size:2.4rem;
     color:#999;

     &--one{
         flex:1;
         display:flex;
         align-items:center;
     } 

     &--two{
         overflow:hidden;

     }

     &__logo-box{
          flex:1;
     }

     &__logo{
         display:block;
         padding:1rem;
     }

     &__navtoggle{
         display:block;
         padding:1rem;
         cursor:pointer;
     }

     &__nav{
         display:flex;
     }

     &__nav-item{
         display:block;
         padding:1rem;
         border-left:.8px solid #000;
         text-decoration:none;
         color:inherit;
         transition:.3s all;

         &:hover{
             background:#bca64b;
             color:#333;
         }
     }
  }


  @media(max-width: 650px){
     .header{
         flex-direction:column;

         &__nav{
             flex-direction:column;
         }

         &--one{
             border-bottom:1px solid #000;
         }

         &--two{
             background:#444;
             display:none;
             animation:slideDown .5s ease-out;
         }

         &--two.show{
             display:block;
         }
     }



 }


 @media(min-width: 651px){

     .header{

         align-items: center;

         &__navtoggle{
             display:none;
         }
     }

 }

 @keyframes slideDown{
     from{height:0;opacity:0;}
     to{height:100%;opacity:1;}
 }
```

JS:

```
  document.querySelector('.header__navtoggle').addEventListener('click',()=>{

        document.querySelector('.header--two').classList.toggle('show');

    });
```

Comment: Can you create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) in SO's editor or https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Your problem is located in the Stylesheet. The 100% height does not work the way you think it should. If you want the element to fill the entire viewport in height, you could use `100vh` instead of `100%`. Maybe this brings you a bit closer to a solution. *Also, as Cesar mentioned it, you should update your question, so that the community can better help you.*

Comment: @Jan I don't want it to extend the entire viewport in height, just the height of the container.

Comment: Here is the codepen if that helps: https://codepen.io/hjb1694/pen/zQdWvO 1

Answer (score 0):

Animation works only with properties that are numbers, like opacity, height, color, etc. It won't work with display, position, float, etc.

You need to replace the `display: block/show` to `height: 0/100px`.